# How to stick to one virtual desktop

Tags: kde

Im Leo
I have a very serious ( Yes for me ) issue, Im new to KDE , switched from Gnome- Ubuntu 2 weeks ago, using linux for a few months now say 6 months.
The thing is when I open a new window in my brave, it opens in an another virtual desktop.
Happens all the time to different windows and diff application
Please help me overcome this
Im using
**KDE Neon 5.24
Plasma version 5.24.5**